# Translating raw mouse/pointer data to something meaningful?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am using the hexdump -C to show realtime data from a pointing device on a linux box. The information it returns is 16 bytes of hex per line. Like this:

> ```
> 000001b0  a9 1c fd 4e f1 2c 0f 00  01 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  |...N.,....>.....|
> 000001c0  a9 1c fd 4e 0e 2d 0f 00  01 00 3e 00 00 00 00 00  |...N.-....>.....|
> 000001d0  a9 1c fd 4e 16 2d 0f 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...N.-..........|
> 000001e0  aa 1c fd 4e b1 9a 05 00  01 00 3d 00 01 00 00 00  |...N......=.....|
> 000001f0  aa 1c fd 4e ce 9a 05 00  01 00 3d 00 00 00 00 00  |...N......=.....|
> 00000200  aa 1c fd 4e d5 9a 05 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...N............|
> ```

My question is, how do I know how to translate this string to the coordinate data from the mouse pointer?

Comment: Ask the manual or the manufacturer. Or do a /lot/ of trial and error!

Comment: Oh, and that's 16 /bytes/ per line, not bits.

Comment: So it is basically a black box? There is no common format for this type of data?

Comment: Surely it's sixteen BYTES of hex per line?  What do you want to do with the hex dump? The characters to the right are the ASCII representation of the data... where it makes sense (if it doesn't make sense, it just leaves a `.`).

Comment: Well they have to be coordinates of some type. I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: Define "useable"? A lot of characters are nulls anyway

Comment: I want to get the coordinates out of the string

Comment: Can you define "pointing device on a linux box" ?

Comment: What _specific_ data type do you actually want the data in? "The coordinate data" is not a data type.

Comment: It is a mouse. @ildjarn whatever form allows me to translate the hex into coordinates.

Comment: @chronoz : "Coordinates" is not a data type.

Comment: "It is a mouse" - could you be a little more specific?  What type of mouse and how is it connected?

Comment: Pointing devices don't return data in "lines." Only hexdump does.  I suggest you do as @Dan suggested and find out what data the device actually provides.

Comment: For the readers, it would be useful to know how you actually obtained the hexdump. Just saying, because there is a difference between USB stream data, output from /dev/input/input*, and output from /dev/input/mouse*, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most USB input devices conform to the [USB HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_human_interface_device_class) specification. The Xorg `evdev(4)` driver should be able to Just Use nearly any pointing device.

If you're writing your own driver, [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/libusb-1.0) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find what is the periodicity and the size (in bytes) of x and y coordinate

you can write a progam that calculates the frequency of the coordinates are written(while moving the device). then you have to calibrate... move the pointer and see the coordinates change... it is globally how i would have done.

Comment: if it is a usb mouse, --> sarnold answer :)   not difficult to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Trial and error maybe? You know your screen's resolution so that may help.
You could try putting the mouse pointer in the top left corner (0, 0) and record what data you get. Hopefuly it should not change if you try and scroll further past the screen (or the data repeats). Then move it to the lower right corner and record what data you get there. Again you're hoping that the values don't change if you try scroll off the screen. Then you can look at the data, fiddle with endianess until the values look right and figure out if there's any scaling going on.

Maybe